# How to activate Paypal plus in my PayPal account?

Tags: paypal, shopware, shopware6

I am trying to set up PayPal plus checkout

but it shows some errors

```
 Refused to set the document's base URI to 'https://www.paypalobjects.com/web/res/3ed/f1a640bec2810a8e5fe6745f75224' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "base-uri 'self' https://*.paypal.com".
```

From some research, I have noticed that we have to sign up for PayPal Plus.

But the `https://www.paypal.com/de/webapps/mpp/paypal-plus` URL is wrong

How we can activate PayPal plus for my sandbox account

I want to set up PayPal implementation for Brazil.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal Plus DE and PayPal Plus for BR/MX are separate products, and are integrated differently.

Here is information about the BR version:

- For the business: https://www.paypal.com/br/webapps/mpp/merchant-integration/solution/direct?tutorial=paypal-payments-pro (portuguese)
- For developers: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/regional/br/

To use PayPal Plus BR in the live/production environment, the account owner needs to contact PayPal and have it approved for the account.

Comment: Do we need PayPal plus approval for a sandbox account?

Comment: No, but you do need to create a PayPal sandbox Business account for the right country, and use that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your site is missing an SSL certificate - did you try it with a valid ssl certificate? Most of the payment providers require nowadays ssl in the storefront to work properly.

Comment: https://shopwaredemo.thebuild.site/paypal-plus/paypalPlus.php

Yes my site has a valid SSL certificate

Answer (score 0):

On the [page linked in the comment](https://shopwaredemo.thebuild.site/paypal-plus/paypalPlus.php) you seem to have an own script for PayPal plus.

You might want to use the standard PayPal Plus extension [as written in the docs](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/extensions/paypal#paypal-plus).

The problem with the linked page is, that the paypal script tried to include code from paypalobjects.com which is forbidden by the content security policy header sent by https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/inlinepaymentwall/payment-selection